# How do I handle response data from payment gateway?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

I'm using the PayPal PayFlow Pro payment gateway.  I've tested the PHP/CURL code given on https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/618 and it returned:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Connection: close Server: VPS-3.033.00
>   X-VPS-Request-ID: 20140619132842 Date: Thu, 19 Jun 2014 20:28:43 GMT
>   Content-type: text/namevalue Content-length: 98
>   RESULT=0&PNREF=A71E6C7596B6&RESPMSG=Approved&AUTHCODE=010101&AVSADDR=Y&AVSZIP=Y&CVV2MATCH=Y&IAVS=N

Can I turn this response into an array or something that I can actually do something with?  I don't know how I'm supposed to handle this data and I couldn't find any clear answers to this that worked when testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP this is fairly easy. Here's a function that can turn it into an array

```
function process_response($str) {
    $data = array();
    $x = explode('&', $str);
    foreach($x as $val) {
         $y = explode('=', $val);
         if(!empty($y[1]))
         $data[$y[0]] = urldecode($y[1]);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

As to the other data, here's an educated guess, based on PayPal Classic NVP

- `RESPMSG` - Looks like the payment was approved
- `CVV2MATCH` - The customer's CVV2 (3 or 4 digit code outside the card number) matched
- `AVS` - The zip code matched the billing zip code
- `PNREF` - Probably the unique identifier used for this transaction. Will probably be used if you need to issue a refund.